# Read data from a database in an android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-intent

This is my code for reading the data from my database. Here I'm just receiving the values and printing them using "Toast" class.

```
public void OnClickLogin(View btnLogin)
{
    String email,password;
    String[] cols = new String[] {DataBase_Server.EMAIL, DataBase_Server.PASS};
    EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    EditText edtLoginId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    DataBase_Server database=new DataBase_Server(login.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.query(DataBase_Server.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    //startManagingCursor(c);
    c.moveToFirst();
    email=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Server.EMAIL));
    password=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Server.PASS));
    Toast.makeText(this,email+" hello "+password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

There are no syntax errors in the code but when I'm running my app and click on my login button I get a force close dialog box which ultimately quits my app and in the "logcat" I see some exception like "Unable to open stack file ......access denied" etc. etc.

logcat:

09-20 00:44:06.755: E/AndroidRuntime(244): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-20 00:44:06.775: E/AndroidRuntime(244): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickLogin(View) in the activity
09-20 00:44:06.805: E/dalvikvm(244): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

logcat

still getting some more error :
logcat :

09-20 00:44:06.755: E/AndroidRuntime(244): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-20 00:44:06.775: E/AndroidRuntime(244): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickLogin(View) in the activity
09-20 00:44:06.805: E/dalvikvm(244): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
09-20 01:22:04.535: E/AndroidRuntime(352): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-20 01:22:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
09-20 01:22:04.555: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2031)
09-20 01:22:04.585: E/dalvikvm(352): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Comment: would be helpful if you appended the error from logcat

Comment: "Database_Server" is the name of my database class where i have created my table

Comment: After fixing your casing on the function name make sure you close the cursor and db before exiting the function.  `c.close(); db.close();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is called

`OnClickLogin`

but in your XML layout file you have declared it as:

`android:onClick="onClickLogin"`

a capital O error. Just rename your method in your class:

`public void onClickLogin(View btnLogin)`

Comment: @rick Yes you are, but that is the answer to this question. Continuing developing and if you are stuck open a new question. This one can be marked as answered http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: logcat :
09-20 01:28:55.524: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

check the spelling, I assume that you specified the click handler in xml which I personally find very error prone. The bug is that the method is spelled `OnClickLogin` whereas you specified `onClickLogin` (notice the lowercase 'o') in the xml. I personally prefer to not specify the clickhandler in XML but specify it via code such as

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
btn.setOnClickHandler(...).
```

Comment: I don't mind using the XML onClick attribute, but I use Annotations to keep myself aware that this method is an entry point into my app: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/using-annotations-for-android-xml-onclick-visibility/